# CircuiTikZ American voltage signs not vertically aligned with unicode-math

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, circuitikz, unicode-math

I am creating a circuit diagram, and noticed that the voltage signs are not aligned vertically.

I have manually added the red overlay to highlight the issue.
[image: XeLaTeX code output]

I used XeLaTeX through LaTeXmk, and here is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \ctikzset{voltage=raised}
    \draw (0, 0) to[R=$R_1$, *-*, v=$v_1$] ++ (-2, 0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

If I remove the `unicode-math` package and `Latin Modern Math` font, then the issue is fixed.
[image: Code output without unicode-math]
Is it possible to fix this issue within `unicode-math`?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Interesting question. I am not sure what happens here, and I have little time to look at it now (I am on vacation!). Could you please try to see how `${}-{}+{}$` renders in the two conditions...

Comment: BTW, reversing the loading order doesn't help.

Comment: It looks to me if the `-` is not in place when I look at the heigths of the rules in respect to the `v`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem: in the standard LaTeX math font, the minus sign has a box that is the same size of the plus sign, and centered. In the Latin Modern Math, the minus has a box which is asymmetric. Look at this example and test with or without `unicode-math` and `Latin Modern Math`...

```latex
% TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \ctikzset{voltage=raised}
    \draw (0.5,1) node[draw,red,thin,inner sep=1pt]{$-$}
            (1,1) node[draw,red,thin,inner sep=1pt]{$+$};
    \draw (0, 0) to[R=$R_1$, *-*, v=$v_1$, name=A] ++ (2, 0);
    \draw[red, opacity=0.5]  (A-Vfrom) -- (A-Vto);
    \ctikzset{voltage/american plus=$+$}
    \ctikzset{voltage/american minus=$\vphantom{+}-$}
    \draw (0, -2) to[R=$R_1$, *-*, v=$v_1$, name=B] ++ (2, 0);
    \draw[red, opacity=0.5]  (B-Vfrom) -- (B-Vto);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With `unicode-math` and the Latin Modern Math:

[image]

Without `unicode-math` (look at the boxes!)

[image]

So the problem is that the minus sign is not centered in its box in `unicode-math`. I do not know if this is a feature or not, but given that `circuitikz` position the nodes one by one, it confounds it.

The workaround, as you see, is using:

```latex
\ctikzset{voltage/american minus=$\vphantom{+}-$}
```

that fixes the position of the minus sign.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer!