# Aligning extra x tick labels horizontally with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, labels

I  am using the following code to plot a graph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=\textwidth,
  height=0.5\textwidth,
  axis lines = center,
  xmin=-40, xmax=40,
  ymin=-0.2, ymax=1.2,
  xtick=\empty,
  ytick={1},
  extra x ticks={-5,5},
  extra x tick labels={$-n$,$n$},
]
\addplot[
  color=blue
]
coordinates {(-40,0)(-5,0)(0,0.33)(0,0.67)(5,1)(40,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

The issue I have is that the labels "-n" and "n" are not horizontally aligned. I would like the "-n" to be higher, aligned with "n". I managed to fix it by adding the line
`extra x tick style={text height=0.15cm}`
in the options of the axis environment. However, this does not satisfy me because the height of 0.15cm is arbitrary and I would like a cleaner way of doing this, to be sure the label "n" does not move.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
extra x tick labels={$-n$,$\vphantom{-}n$},
```

or

```
extra x tick labels={$\smash{-}n$,$n$},
```

the problem is that the minus sign [has a funny behavior](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/609201/circuitikz-american-voltage-signs-not-vertically-aligned-with-unicode-math) in Computer Modern...

[This issue](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/721) is why I suspected it...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works (I didn't know about phantom commands). However, I should have stated things more clearly (I edited the question): I would like the label "n" not to move from its current location, and move the "-n" higher up. Is that possible?

Comment: Not at computer now... The important thing is to have them on the same line, then you can use the `style` option for ticks to move then. Anyway, you can try `\smash` on the minus or adding a `\strut` to both.

Comment: I used ```\smash``` that's what I was looking for. Thank you!